# My hobby? Stackoverflow-ing

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I went for an informal job interview some weeks back. I was asked what other hobbies/interests do I have beside those mentioned in my CV.

I thought for a second (0.732 to be exact) and replied, "Stackoverflow-ing".

Is that something you will do? My reply came out without hesitation and I'm wondering if it make any sense.

PS: I'll leave this as a Community Wiki post (kind of expecting it to be closed too :P)

Comment: "Superuser-ing" would sound a bit pretentious, though.

Comment: I wouldn't know for what job I should apply to with my SU rep anyway @Gnoupi

Comment: What about "Serverfault-ing"?

Comment: Isn't .732 seconds how long Data thought about becoming a Borg in Star Trek: First Contact?

Comment: You're really hoping Randall Munroe reads meta, aren't you?

Comment: @pop: I think he is. The XKCD reference density in this post is beyond acceptable norms.

Comment: @Ivo - customer support, of course! In a very general field, with preferably lot of beginners who also have an iPhone to ask question about, when you are done with their computer.

Comment: So when are we getting a Super User Careers site? @Gnoupi

Comment: @Gnoupi I prefer suing (su==super user + unix command). Course no one will hire you if you say that.

Answer (score 12):

They might assume you are joking about how often your code literally produces a stack overflow, to which they will laugh heartily *"Oh ho-ho!"* ... and then will write in a private note:

> *Writes code that crashes and thinks it's funny -- NO HIRE*

Comment: hahaha that's funny. really :P

Comment: *"Writes code that crashes and thinks it's funny -- NO HIRE - Perhaps hire as entertainment for next company meeting...?"*

Comment: @Polly more like "Writes code that crashes and thinks it's funny -- NO HIRE - possibly next motivational speaker?"

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that will make no sense unless the interviewer knows what StackOverflow.com is. That could be good or bad. Depends on the person.

Unless you got this offer through careers.stackoverflow.com? haha, then you might be in business.

Comment: Of course I did explain further what SO is about :P

Comment: "Unless you got this offer through careers.stackoverflow.com? haha, then you might be in business."

They would probably put you in their Dept. of Redundancy Dept then.

Answer (score 1):

Reworking the wording would likely pass better. At the very least explain (briefly) that you are part of a community of enthusiast programming experts.

Also, you like golf. If your answer is no, you are wrong. You like golf, starting now.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that you should use hobbies/interests to demonstrate that you do things other than programming/development.  Usually team sports, but also things that could be indirectly related to what you work on - business knowledge is as valuable, if not more in some situations.

Comment: Yes of course :) SO is not my only 'hobby'.